# Dropping peer, but peer seems to be fine

Tags: stellar-core, peers

In Stellar Core 10.0.0, I keep seeing log entries like this:

```
I  2018-09-25T03:35:16.416 GBCS2 [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 52.55.85.153:11625
I  2018-09-25T03:35:16.516 GBCS2 [Overlay INFO] successful handshake with tempo@52.55.85.153:11625
I  2018-09-25T03:35:16.665 GBCS2 [Overlay WARNING] Received error (ERR_LOAD): peer rejected
I  2018-09-25T03:35:16.665 GBCS2 [Overlay INFO] Dropping peer tempo@52.55.85.153:11625
```

But based on https://dashboard.stellar.org/, as far as I can tell, Tempo is up (a handshake occurs, after all). Anyone know why this might be happening?